# How can I fix these suspenders?

Tags: clothing

I have a pair of climbing pants with suspenders. One of the metal thingies, let's call them clips, bent and no longer held. I attempted to bend it back in shape, but it broke. The picture will make it clear, hopefully.
Is there a product available off the shelf, or something that can be made, that would work in place of these clips?

I considered bending metal wire (but it would be hard to unclip, if need be), and small carabiners (would be 5.5 cm in length, bulky and would not be comfortable under the backpack waist belt).

[image]

Comment: Just my opinion, in case it happens again, heating the hinge could make the task of bending metal easier

Comment: Once bent, a metal casting cannot be re-bent. The metal has been fractured. Bending wire will make a clip but it will fracture at the bend where the strength is weakest and the mechanical advantage is the greatest. Using heat-treatment it is possible to make a hardened steel clip; but, it will be easier to contact the supplier for a replacement. It's a poor design and you've discovered why.

Comment: @Stan yes, but it's just a pair of suspenders.

Comment: @Carl - Exactly my point.

Answer (score 3):

Try substituting two split key rings and a snap.

Here's a sketch I had fun making to give you an idea of what I had in mind. I'd guess that 1-1/4" diameter rings should work. It's not ideal but the materials should be easy to find and you could make two so that they'd match. They'll lie flat against your body. The adjustment buckle should take up the slack.

[image: substitute suspender clip]

Another idea was to use a small "S" shaped carabiner which is easy to attach and relatively flat against your body.

Comment: I don’t think the hook between the split rings would be sturdy enough.

Comment: @M.Mat Maybe there's another better choice. This was something I drew quickly to present the idea using common "find-around-the-house" things.

Comment: The idea is good just the hook needs to be more sturdy, especially for climbing.